# selenium IDE - how to simulate a down-arrow key press on a select?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, keyboard-events, arrow-keys

I have a select dropdown for time with the current time + 1/2 hour pre-selected (so changes frequently) by the application server (rails).

How can I arrow-down 6 times (the increments are half hours) to pick the value currently selected plus 3 hours?

I've tried using `sendKeys` but can see any way to pass 'downArrow'

I've tried `keyPress` with a value of `\\40` but that didn't do anything (no error).

I can't used a fixed index as the preselected time on the dropdown is frequently changing.
The dropdown always has the same number of elements - about 48.

I've tried using the deprecated `keyDown()` but that didn't seem to work (though no error, just no change).

I'm also wondering if I might be able to somehow find and store the current option index (as a variable) from the existing page and then use that +3 to 'reselect' the option I want?
This would start with

```
storeElementIndex
//select[@id='reservation_end_time']/option[@selected='selected']
current_time_index
```

and then have

```
select
id=reservation_end_time
index=${current_time_index}+4
```

but I get `[error] Illegal Index: 25+4`

I've also tried:

```
store
${current_time_index}+4
new_time
```

with

```
storeElementIndex
//select[@id='reservation_end_time']/option[@selected='selected']
current_time_index

select
id=reservation_end_time
index=${new_time}
```

but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for down-arrow key press, please try the IDE steps given below.

```
     command          |         target               |        value
storeSelectedIndex    |  id=reservation_end_time     |  currentIndex
storeEval             |  ${currentIndex}+6           |  requiredIndex
select                |  id=reservation_end_time     |  index=${requiredIndex}
```

Let me know if this helps you.